# AngularJS handle rejected response with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

I have a Service which wraps my API calls in Angular:

```
var ConcernService = {

    list: function (items_url) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', 
            url: api_url + items_url})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.resolve(data, status);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.reject(data, status);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    },
```

Then my app config, with `UI-Router`:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider){

        $stateProvider

        .state('default', {
            url: '/',
            resolve: {
                tasks: function ($stateParams, ConcernService) {
                    return ConcernService.list('tasks/').then(
                        function (tasks)   { return tasks; },
                        function (reason)  { return []; }
                    );
                },
                ...
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the most basic configuration I could get away with, which basically just returns an empty object if a `403`, `404` etc is encountered and I can handle that in the view, template.

My question is, what is the best approach for getting the other detail to the view/ template, such as the rejection `reason` and `status`. Should it be returned in the `tasks` object, or separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first of all, your first bit of code has the [deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1348195), let's fix that:

```
list: function (items_url) {
    return $http.get(api_url + items_url); // $http already returns a promise
},
```

Also note, that deferred rejections and fulfillments are single value, so your multiple return values don't really work here.

Now, let's look at the router. First of all, your first fulfillment handler is redundant.

```
.state('default', {
        url: '/',
        resolve: {
            tasks: function ($stateParams, ConcernService) {
                return ConcernService.list('tasks/'); // result.data contains the data here
            },
            ...
        }
```

Now, the problem we have here is what happens in case of a rejection?

Well, listen to `$stateChangeError`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ ... })
```

Here, you can listen to change state failures from rejections.

Comment: Hey Benjamin - thanks for the pointers on my code. I did think it was a little long-winded. I do understand promises a little better now. As for the state change error expression - should this go in my `app.config`? And then do a just map the various errors to the states I want?

Comment: Right. Implementation works. for the record I added the `stateChangeError` statement to the `app.run()`, and I can pass along the error object to a generic partial template to display context-specific messages. Thanks!